# Result not getting into scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In the below scenario.I am calling getRole function which is in different js.It is expected to return json object.But problem looks like here is one more parallel thread is running in below code.so the expected result is not coming in below scope.I want getRole function should finish first and return the result and assigned to below scope.

```
 $scope.callFilter=function(result){

                      $scope.resultObject=getRole();


                     };
```

below is getRole

```
function getRole(){


//intranetId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
intranetId ="TAPAS.BANDYOPADHYAY@IN.IBM.COM";

var valuesArray = "";
var valuesArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map( function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");

alert(valuesArray);





var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'RoleAdapter',
        procedure : 'getRoles',
        parameters :[intranetId,'all',valuesArray]

    };
 var options = {
            onSuccess : getRoleSuccess,
            onFailure : getRoleFailure,

    };
 WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);}

function getRoleSuccess(result){
//alert("inside getRoleSuccess");
var httpStatusCode = result.status;
if (200 == httpStatusCode) {        
    var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
    var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
    if (true == isSuccessful) {

        var text_json = invocationResult.text;
        var json_parse = JSON.parse(text_json);
        alert("json"+text_json);
        role=json_parse;//JSON.parse(int);
        var elementExist=document.getElementById("myForm");
        if(elementExist!== null){
         document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }else{
        return text_json;

    }

    }
else {
    alert("Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode);
    return false;
}
}
else{
    alert("http Failure");
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: is there any rest calls inside getRole()?

Comment: You should be making a service for such api calls and then bind it to your controller.For a test try returning a static value  in the callFilter function and see if it gets to the view using the $scope.

Comment: yes,one more function call inside getRole.which is in same js

Answer (score 0):

Problem is evident. Your getRole method is not returning anything. It is invoking an asynchronous operation and returning immediately

`WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);`

May be you can refactor your code a bit to achieve what you aim. Using **callback**,

Please note that getRole method you are using is not optimal, it is not handling failures and other error scenarios.

```
$scope.callFilter=function(result){
    getRole(function(result){
       $scope.resultObject= result;
       $scope.$apply(); // so that angular is aware value changed
    });
};
```

And

```
function getRole(callback){


//intranetId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
intranetId ="TAPAS.BANDYOPADHYAY@IN.IBM.COM";

var valuesArray = "";
var valuesArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map( function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");

alert(valuesArray);





var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'RoleAdapter',
        procedure : 'getRoles',
        parameters :[intranetId,'all',valuesArray]

    };

 WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
            onSuccess : function (result){
                var httpStatusCode = result.status;
                if (200 == httpStatusCode) {        
                    var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
                    var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
                    if (true == isSuccessful) {

                        var text_json = invocationResult.text;
                        var json_parse = JSON.parse(text_json);
                        alert("json"+text_json);
                        role=json_parse;//JSON.parse(int);
                        var elementExist=document.getElementById("myForm");

                        if(callback) {
                            callback(role);
                        }

                        if(elementExist!== null){
                            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
                        }else{
                            return text_json;

                        }

                    }
                else {
                    alert("Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode);
                    return false;
                }
                }
                else{
                    alert("http Failure");
                    return false;
                }},

            onFailure : getRoleFailure

    };
);
```

}